# How to get a built docker image within a codepipeline to the deploy step with blue/green-deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I've got a flow where I want a codepipeline to trigger on git commits on Github, go via some test and build steps and end in a codedeploy step where the code will be deployed on a ECS cluster with blue/green-deployment. But I'm stuck on the last step on how to get the image to the CodeDeploy-step.

The pipeline looks like this:

Source (GitHub) -> Test -> Build, creates a docker image which is uploaded to ECR. Artifact contains appspec.yaml, taskdefinition.json, imagedefinitions.json. -> Deploy (CodeDeployToECS), using artifact from the build step.

The last step in the pipeline is configured with the "CodeDeployToECS" provider. But what I cannot get my head around is how I get the image that is created in the build step to end up in the CodeDeploy step which is using blue/green-deployment.

I've checked out this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-ecs-ecr-codedeploy.html but they are using a image from the source step as artifact in the CodeDeploy step which don't match my use case.

This guide is to deploy with ECS with a rolling update which creates, on the fly, a imagedefinitions.json that I'm trying to apply but won't work: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cd-pipeline.html

With the above setup the Deploy step just tells me the image artifact is invalid. Any pointers if this is possible or any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, to create a image artifact you need to generate the file `imageDetail.json` which is a JSON object with one property named ImageURI with the URI to the image. I followed this thread to get to this fact: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=881131

Comment: Indeed -- in the AWS doc linked from the very last post on that article, "The imageDetail.json file was previously not referenced in the CodePipeline User Guide... " would have been very nice to know when we were configuring the pipeline. We use the printf method in our build step to create the imageDetail.json file.